# How can you calculate available storage space in the Apple Watch?

Tags: local-storage, apple-watch, watchos

I've been trying to find a workable solution to determine if I have room to allocate an array of files to the Apple Watch before I attempt any file transfer at all, and I've come up with nothing so far. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSFileManager works the same way for the Apple Watch as it does on other devices.

In Objective-C:

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize]
```